# Webscrape containers with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, containers

I'm trying to webscrape content from the containers on this webpage: https://www.check24.de/handytarife/vergleich?activeForm=sim

I'm usually webscraping using beautifulsoup but in this case, I've found out that it is not working for this website. When I run my 'soup', I get only details of the website architecture instead of content from the containers available on the website.

```
page_link = 'check24.de/handytarife/vergleich?activeForm=sim' 
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text,'lxml')
```

Would you know any good Python library able to do what I'm trying to do?

Best,
Sam

Comment: Share your code along with current and desired output

Comment: page_link = 'https://www.check24.de/handytarife/vergleich?activeForm=sim'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text,'lxml')

Comment: I'd like to get all of the items in each of the containers on the website. For example, LTE Special, LTE All 3 GB...

Comment: `requests` cannot handle URL without schema. That's your first problem. The second problem is that page you're requesting contain no required data.

Comment: I don't really understand why it contains no required data?

Comment: because all data comes from XHR which you need to request with another GET-request. Also *"I'd like to get all of the items in each of the containers"* is not a good description of *"desired output"*. Which data exactly you need? What format of data?

Comment: I'd like to get the prices in each container. Example: the first one is 5,07€, the second one is 7,32€ etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to request just an HTML page which is more like *an empty pretty frame for a raw data*. All data comes from XHR

You can get all data in JSON format as below:

```
r = requests.get('https://mobilfunk.check24.de/ajax/result/collection/sim?network_tmobile=yes&network_vodafone=yes&network_o2=yes&data_included=2000&minutes_included=all&select_contract=-24&young_tariff=no&rnp=egal&data_speed=0&lte=no&with_data_tariffs=no&with_high_rejection_rate=all&fixed_traffic_automatic=egal&sms_included=all&tid=CH24_MF_Default').json()
```

As you didn't tell what *exactly you need to scrape* here is how you can get all *names*:

```
for item in r['rows']:
    print(item['tariff']['names']['resultlist'])
```

Comment: How did you find the link for XHR?

Comment: @sammtt , you can press F12 -> switch to network tab -> select XHR subtab only -> refresh page... you should see all the XHRs that send while page rendering

Comment: thanks but I can't find any link when i now try to get the json from https://www.check24.de/dsl/vergleich/?olduri=0&compare_dsl_handy_input=compare_dsl&dsl_handy_input_page=input2&fakepassword=&c24_controller=result&c24api_calculationparameter_id=d7b4f9a5c2b9f145ac65c5151cd3c61d366c173f47a66b213716a9d63017b6346edc7e2416e069faf4e61b3c444c5d07dba99c26e7e101aa0d0ef57be222e0f8&c24api_page=1&c24api_sortfield=&c24api_sortorder=asc#tko-result-container

Comment: @sammtt , now the data is in page source. In this request you're sending all required parameters in the first request, so no need in additional requests